# Activity Tab in Profile Gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, activity-tab

I know MSO has been testing changes to the profile page, but did I miss the announcement about the activity tab in my profile on StackOverflow going away? I'd swear that it was there as of yesterday.

Comment: It seems to be gone on all the sites (that I checked).

Comment: This was just brought up [over on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244656/where-are-my-comments-from-the-activity-tab) too.

Comment: So, how can I find my old comments now?

Comment: Oded is fixing it apparently.

Comment: @Grant Meta.SO is currently running on a separate build because of the redesign, so changes don't always appear on both sites simultaneously. You can see the build numbers at the very bottom of the footer.

Comment: It is on the way back. Next build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is my bad - when testing, I missed that the activity tab was gone (we have so many of them tabs on the profile page).

It is back where it belongs.